# Redeploying React Application on GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, web-deployment, github-pages

I deployed my React application on [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/) and now I want to make some changes to my application and redeploy it after making the necessary changes to the application. In order to deploy my application for the first time on GitHub pages, I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages). I was wondering if the process gonna be the same if I'm gonna be redeploying it or do I have to follow a different procedure for redeploying it.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if we want to make some changes to our React application that has already been deployed on the [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/) and redeploy it on GitHub Pages after making the necessary changes, then what we can do is that, once we are done with making then necessary changes to our application, then we can follow the [same tutorial](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) that I have mentioned in my question above.